# T-SQL Group operation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have two tables as shown below:

```
**tblComments**
Commentid
addeddate
Postid


**tblPosts**
Postid
AddedBy
AddedDate
Title
```

I want to find the total comments for each post. How to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To produce zero for post without comments, T-SQL:

```
select
    P.postid, count(c.postid) -- should not use COUNT(*) for LEFT JOINs
from
    tblPosts P 
    LEFT JOIN
    tblComments C On P.postid  = C.postid 
group by
    P.postid
```

For Postgresql, get the cardinality of rows:

```
select
    P.postid, count(c.*) -- should not use COUNT(*) for LEFT JOINs
from
    tblPosts P 
    LEFT JOIN
    tblComments C On P.postid  = C.postid 
group by
    P.postid
```

Related to this: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/04/debunking-myth-that-countdracula-is.html

This is why COUNT(*) should not be used on LEFT JOINs:

```
create table posts
(
post_id int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
post varchar(max)
);

create table comments
(
post_id int not null references posts(post_id),
comment_id int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
comment varchar(max)
);

insert into posts(post) values('hello');

insert into posts(post) values('oh hai');
insert into comments(post_id,comment) values(SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 1);

-- don't
select p.post_id, COUNT(*) as comment_count from
posts p
left join comments c on c.post_id = p.post_id
group by p.post_id

-- do
select p.post_id, COUNT(c.post_id) as comment_count from
posts p
left join comments c on c.post_id = p.post_id
group by p.post_id
```

Output:

```
post_id     comment_count
----------- -------------
1           1
2           1


post_id     comment_count
----------- -------------
1           0
2           1
```

Query-style is more appealing on Postgresql, come to think of it, what we are really counting is the cardinality of the set, not the column(s):

```
-- looks better on Postgresql, COUNT(c.*)
select p.post_id, COUNT(c.*) as comment_count from
posts p
left join comments c on c.post_id = p.post_id
group by p.post_id
```

Comment: Can you justify why not COUNT(*) for LEFT JOINs? Sounds like superstition to me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1/1221649#1221649

Comment: @gbn: it's not superstition, it will still produce a count of 1 even if the `post` doesn't have any corresponding `comments` if you are using left join.  you try it. you try to read the article why i also don't believe in using COUNT(1), I encourage the use of `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(table.*)` (if on Postgresql)

Comment: the article: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/04/debunking-myth-that-countdracula-is.html

Comment: oops, yes, I was too hasty in interpreting your code comments

Answer (score 3):

You need to join the tables to find posts with no comment to generate zero

```
select
    count(c.postid), P.postid --edit
from
    tblPosts P 
    LEFT JOIN
    tblComments C On P.postid  = C.postid 
group by
    P.postid
```

Comment: that query will still produce a count of 1 even the tblPosts don't have any comments. change the `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(c.postid)`.  If on Postgres, change the `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(c.*)`.  If you do so, I'll upvote you and remove my answer

Comment: here's the complete example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561020/t-sql-group-operation/4561081#4561081

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*), postid from tblPosts group by postid
```

should do the trick I would have thought

Comment: thanks..for those posts which do not have comments, how to put 0 for them

Comment: @Bujo, check my query :-) and related article

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Edited based on your comment below to get all posts including those with 0 comments.
Try it out. I think this should work as you expect

```
SELECT p.Postid, p.Title, ISNULL(X.count,0)
FROM tblPosts p
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   (SELECT postid, count(commentid) as Total
   FROM tblComments
   GROUP BY Postid) AS X
ON p.Postid = X.Postid
```

Comment: thanks..for those posts which do not have comments, how to put 0 for them

Comment: @gbn Totally...I like your query better as well!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
select case(when count(commentid)>0 then count(commentid) else 0 end), postid from tblPosts group by postid
```